# How to give last class name, some other css

Tags: css

I have some panel in the CMS TYPO3 with Bootstrap, so it's a bootstrap panel/div.
The div class is named "panel panel-default" and i have 5 in a row.

I can't add an extra name to the class so I need to use the Panel and Panel-default classes in my CSS.

My question is, how can I in my CSS, add a speciel style so the last Panel/div with the class names..

```
 class="panel panel-default"
```

Have another style, then the 4. first panel's/div's.

---

EDIT.

Hi thx for the last-child.

But its not working, I think its the div structure, but I can't change that, now do is add a speciel style on the last div here ?
If i add the last-child on the class, it make the style on the 2 div's here.

```
<div id="c182">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="c178">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean `:last-child`? Without seeing the full HTML it's hard to provide the correct answer.

Comment: did you try to use this `:last-child`?

Comment: as last-child is an element selector, please note that if you have another div after the last `div.panel-default`, the last-child selector won't work - http://jsfiddle.net/8M9Vd/1/

Comment: @Pete Since we don't have any further information, we all can assume only and can give answer accordingly.

Comment: Thomas it looks like there is a container div for the divs with the ids c182 and c178. if so you can do:  `#containerDivId > div:last-child .panel-default`

Comment: Pete give an answer, I tryed #DivID.div:last-child..and that diden't work, so thx Pete.

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen have you used `:last-of-type` selector? check the Demo. http://jsbin.com/zodofiva/1/edit

Comment: @ThomasBøgPetersen can you provide surrounding html as well for your panels as I thought your structure is [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/GLzF9/1/) due to the last closing div but realised it isn't

Answer (score 0):

`.panel.panel-default:last-child
{ 
   your styles
}`

This should select the last `div` with those classes.

To see `:last-child` support, you can look [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child).

#### Update

Since your structure is more complicated than that, how about:

```
div[id]:last-child > div.panel.panel-default {
    your styles
}
```

This will select the `div` with class `.panel.panel-default` that has a direct parent that is the last `div` with an `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
.panel.panel-default:last-child {

your code

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:last-of-type` selector.

```
div:last-of-type .panel-default {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-style: italic;
  color:cyan;
}
```

Here is the **[Demo.](http://jsbin.com/zodofiva/1/edit)**